# $\frac{\log{x}}{x^{\epsilon}}$ Tends to 0 as x Tends to Infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, prime-numbers

$\theta(x) :=\sum_{p\leq x}\log{p}$, and $\epsilon>0$. It is written at the end that-

> The second term on the RHS tends to 0 as x → ∞, and the lemma follows:
>   by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small we can make the ratios of ϑ(x) to x
>   and π(x) to x/ log x arbitrarily close together as x → ∞, so if one of
>   them tends to 1, then so must the other.

I couldn't understand -

1. How the  second term on the RHS tends to 0 as x → ∞?
2. How by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small we can make the ratios of ϑ(x) to x and π(x) to x/ log x arbitrarily close together as x → ∞ ?

The source of the question is below theorem-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $x=e^y$

$$\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}=\frac{y}{e^{\epsilon y}}$$

and for any $\epsilon>0$ eventually $e^{\epsilon y}\ge y^2$.

For the second part since $\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}\to 0$ for any $\epsilon >0$, we can make $\frac{\theta(x)}x$ arbitraly close to $\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}$.

Comment: If we choose $x=e^y$, then $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ becomes negative, then the gap between $\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ and $ \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$ is large, then how$\pi(x)\log(x)/x$ becomes close to $ \frac{\theta(x)}{x}$?