# How $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x=1$ can be derived from $1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, proof-explanation

Could any one please elaborate how $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x=1$ can be derived from $1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda$?
I have taken it granted that $1/\lambda<f(x)/x<\lambda$.

The question is taken from below proof- [image]

PS: I made a mistake in previous post so, I am re-posting.

Comment: "These inequalities hold for all $\lambda > 1$"...

Comment: @amsmath not wise enough to get through that particular line :)

Answer (score 2):

Pay close attention to the following fragment of the proof: "These inequalities hold for all $\lambda \gt 1$."  In particular, consider $\lambda$ arbitrarily close to the value one.

Comment: How do we know $\lambda$ arbitrarily close to the value 1 ?

Comment: Plz note that i don't have knowledge to infer from  "These inequalities hold for all $\lambda \gt 1$.", if possible elaborate.

Comment: You don't need much "knowledge" for this. It's trivial.

Comment: Go back to the second and third sentences of the proof.  It's simply a matter of decoding what is assumed.  You decode using the definitions.  For example, you use the definition of a definite integral that is improper because it has infinity as the upper bound.

Comment: Your question does identify the key point.  Once you are trying to answer your own question, the second and third sentences of the proof become more interesting and easier to understand.  So the process we're going through here suggests an alternative presentation that might be more natural for some readers.

Comment: @amsmath: using the label "trivial" doesn't automatically make it trivial for the student.  You're describing your own evaluation of it.  Also, remember that people stumble over molehills, not mountains.  So, if somebody is stumbling and it is a trivial molehill, then it's a normal situation (as opposed to orthonormal or paranormal maybe).

Comment: Tried failed , I have problem understanding similar arguments see the first comment of the answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3404387/613063    , it would be helpful if yo spell out. btw, agree with your previous comment,

Comment: @Andrew First look at the statement of Lemma 16.8 and explain how the definition of F(x) was invented.  Hint: look up the definition of a definite integral from a constant to infinity.  Second, look up the definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ for any given function g(x).  For it to exist, we need it to be Cauchy, meaning that no matter how small a positive real h is, if we pick large enough r, and choose x > r and y > r, then the absolute value of ( g(x) - g(y) ) needs to be smaller than r.  Now we have the tricky part ahead.  Reformulate that by replacing y with $ (\lambda \cdot x) $.

Comment: The tricky part may be a bit too tricky for my above sloppy comment.  If $ \lambda > 1$, then it seems that we need to show that we can assume without loss of generality that no matter how small a positive real h is, we can pick large enough r so that x > r and y > x and $\vert g(x) - g(y) \vert < h$.  Notice that I wrote "y > x" this time instead of "y > r."  I also made $\vert g(x) - g(y) \vert$ small by making it less than h.  It's too late for me to edit my previous comment.

Comment: @RenEhDaycart okay then I have to start from the scratch then, probably i will ask a more detail question,  but it would be nice if u compile all of your comments, arrange them , add give more direct explanation instead of hints in your answer, thanks for your help. BTW, I am busy with current topic I 'll check your other answer later.

Comment: @Andrew You're absolutely right in terms of Stack Exchange policies that it is preferred to have all important points in the answer that one posts.  However, I was thinking that hints are more helpful for people who are self-motivated learners and who aren't facing any obvious language barrier.  You are allowed to post an answer to your own question using my hints, and then I could suggest edits if you bring your answer to my attention.  You're making me aware of the importance of the following tag: proof-explanation.